# Why is Google App Engine servlet getting old no more exist data from file?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine servlet, it's supposed to go to my site and get a file, then display the content of that file on the servlet served page, the code looks like this :

```
public class My_Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
  public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
  {
    super.init(config);
    System.gc();
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
  {
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    out.println(getTextFile());
}

String getTextFile()
{
  String Text="";

  try
  {
    URL url=new URL("http://example.com/A_Dir/Test.txt");
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;

    while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null) { Text+=line+"<Br>"; }
    reader.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e) {  }

  return Text;
}
```

It worked, but the problem is, after I changed the content in the file "Test.txt" on my site, the Google App is still displaying old data, I checked and double checked the file on my site, the old data is no longer there, and I thought every time I clicked the link served by the GAE, it will call `getTextFile()`, create the URL, go get the file and parse the lines, but it seems GAE is remembering old data from 3 days ago, and no matter how many times I refreshed the page or updated the GAE app and reloaded it on to the App Engine [and I can see the change made to the updated servlet], it's still serving the more then 3 day old data, why? How to force it dynamically load that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE is caching the file. Try:

```
URL url=new URL("http://mysite.com/A_Dir/Test.txt?r="+System.currentTimeMillis());
```